# Does Google Places Autocomplete cost money?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api

I'm trying to understand if Google would charge me for using the `findAutocompletePredictions()` function from their Places API.
This is the function I'm using in my app:

```
fun queryPlaces(searchText: String?) {
    val request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
        .setSessionToken(token)
        .setQuery(searchText)
        .build()

    placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request).addOnSuccessListener { response ->
        searchResults = ArrayList(response.autocompletePredictions)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        if (exception is ApiException) {
            Log.e("searchtext", "Place not found: " + exception.statusCode)
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked around their documentation and I've notice 2 options that possibly match my case:

1. https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#ac-no-details-session
2. https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#ac-with-details-session

Which one of them matches my code?

Comment: Yes, you need to add billing account

Comment: Looks like option 1. You query the autocomplete api without calling `fetchPlace()`. The example in your link is pretty clear.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann Alright, option 1 isn't free, so I want to change my code to match option 2 because it's free. How can I do that?

Comment: @AlexeyBilousov I know, but will they charge me if I use this code?

Comment: @Rondev There is no free option. The example at option 2 shows this: "On your bill, you will see the following SKUs listed (when viewing your bill by SKU):
- Autocomplete (included with Places Details) – Per Session (billed at 0.00 USD)
- Places Details (price starting at 0.017 USD per session)
- Basic Data (billed at 0.00 USD)"

The auto completion is only free because you pay for the `fetchPlace()` in the same session. If you don't make a call to `fetchPlace()`, you pay for the autocompletion.